# How to upload files via https on CSRF enabled website using CURL in Shell?

Tags: linux, shell, curl, https, csrf

I need to login into a website via https protocol using **[CURL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL)** and upload a file in a specific folder. I able to login into the website via curl on CSRF enabled website via HTTPS. However am unable to upload the file. I guess its because of **[CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)** token enabled for HTTPS protocol. **So i need to figure out how to handle CSRF token and upload the file using CURL command via HTTPS protocol.**

Login Format:(Working)

```
curl -u username:password https://ftp.example.com
```

Upload Format:(Not Working)

```
curl -k -T "./testfile.txt" -u "username":"password" https://example.com/upload/
```

Note 1: I am currently running this command RHEL 6.

Note 2: I need to handle CSRF token.

Note 3: Am able to login/upload via ftp and sftp protocols.

I would greatly appreciate a solution for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Working Solution!**

Finally some how i managed to find a solution for this,

All we need to download the CSRF token in the first connection and then use the downloaded CSRF token on the second attempt of connections. Let's see the sample script below.

```
#!/bin/sh

logs_path="/home/usr/logs" #Change your path here
my_username="testuser"     #Change your username here
my_password="testuser"     #Change your password here
host_name="localhost.com"  #Change your sitename here   

touch "$logs_path/testfile.test"

curl -k -c "$logs_path/cookies.txt" -u "$my_username":"$my_password" "https://$host_name:443" > /dev/null 2>&1

curl -k -b "$logs_path/cookies.txt" -T "$logs_path/testfile.test" -u "$my_username":"$my_password" "https://$host_name:443/puts/" > /dev/null 2>&1

status="$?"
if [[ $status == 0 ]]; then
echo -e "\nSuccess!"
else
echo -e "\nFailed!"
fi
```